# Vb.Net - How do i get specific text from webbrowser and display in textbox

Tags: vb.net, web

I want to navigate to a webpage - `WebBrowser1.Navigate("")`
and then copy specific text from the web page and display it in a textbox.

How may i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Start with hooking the [`DocumentCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event.  Then look at getting hold of the elements/text you require through the [`Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Comment: Post some of the code you've tried and where and why you're stuck, so this isn't just a "can you write this code for me" question